# HeidiSQL line numbers in query results window

Tags: heidisql

Well...the title says it all.
I'd like the query result window to show line numbers on the left edge.
Is this possible in HeidiSQL

Thanks!

Comment: There's no built in feature like that now. But go to the forum on the HeidiSQL web site and ask for it. Ansgar Becker, the author, listens to suggestions from users.

Comment: See the discussion in the forum: https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=22407